# Higher Order Non homogeneous Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you please show me how to find the general solution for these differential equations.

1. $y'''-3y''+3y'-y=te^t$  ($3^{rd}$ order)
2. $y''''-2y'''+2y''=te^{t} \cos(t)$ ($4^{th}$ order)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend following Amzoti's advice on the second one.  As to the first, it can be rewritten as

$$e^{-t}y'''-3e^{-t}y''+3e^{-t}y'-3e^{-t}y=t$$
$$(e^{-t}y)'''=t$$

Simply integrate both sides 3 times and multiply by $e^t$ to solve for $y$.